# How to display bag file in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, rosbag, vlp-16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am new on ROS and Linux. I am trying to display point cloud using rviz with VLP-16. Before starting to see real time data, I wanted to see how pcap file can be converted into human-readable, and visible data. So I used pcap file (downloaded from [www.velodynelidar.com](http://www.velodynelidar.com)) to convert to bag file as follows:

```
$ rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _mol:=VLP16 _pcap:=/home/soowon/Documents/County_Fair.pcap _read_once:=true
```

On new terminal, to record pcap data into bag file:

```
$ rosrun rosbag record -O Countyfair.bag /velodyne_packets
```

ON new terminal, I used rosbag to play bag file that I just made:

```
$ rosbag play Countyfair.bag
```

Another new terminal, to open rviz:

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
```

Problem starts from here.

1. I cannot see anything on the screen, even though I added PointCloud, PointCloud2. In rviz, it says "No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist."
2. Not only that I want to see point cloud in rviz, my ultimate goal is acquiring xyz coordinates for each frame. Can you guys tell me where can I find this data?

Any advice? I would appreciate :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227205/how-to-display-bag-file-in-rviz/) by [Soowon](https://answers.ros.org/users/26008/soowon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably forgot to set the [rviz fixed frame](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Coordinate_Frames) to `velodyne`.

**EDIT**: You are not running the `velodyne_pointcloud` nodelet. That is the component that translates the raw packets into a point cloud.

You can use this launch script to view your PCAP data directly:

```
$ roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch pcap:=/home/soowon/Documents/County_Fair.pcap
```

If you want to do it as described above in your question, be sure to spell the `model` parameter correctly:

```
$ rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _model:=VLP16 _pcap:=/home/soowon/Documents/County_Fair.pcap
```

Then, run the point cloud node:

```
$ rosrun velodyne_pointcloud cloud_node _calibration:=$(rospack find velodyne_poitncloud)/params/VLP16db.yaml
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Soowon](https://answers.ros.org/users/26008/soowon/) on 2016-02-22**:
Thank you for helping me :). I tried rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne, as described in the ros tutorial, however, still I could not see any data from the view. In rviz, it says
No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [velodyne] does not exist
Can you give me help on this?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-22**:
You should try leaving off the `_read_once` option. The file may have finished playing before your rviz started running.

**Comment by [Soowon](https://answers.ros.org/users/26008/soowon/) on 2016-02-22**:
Thanks! It really help me! Now I can see point cloud on RViz. But now, it flickers so many times as if the data is interpreted in a wrong way. This data is given from the velodyne website, so I am sure that the data is not corrupted.

**Comment by [Soowon](https://answers.ros.org/users/26008/soowon/) on 2016-02-22**:
Also, it still shows that I have No tf data. Does it matter? And the duration of the data is longer than 200 seconds, so I am pretty sure that I didn't miss the data while trying to figure out tf data. Would you explain me how to set a fixed frame with respect to the center of the laser? Thanks :)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-24**:
The `velodyne` frame *is* relative to the center of the laser.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-24**:
Please edit your question to describe what you are doing now. Running `rosbag record` and `rosbag play` at the same time is probably not a good idea. Does the `VPL16_points.launch` script work?

**Comment by [sohel](https://answers.ros.org/users/32541/sohel/) on 2017-11-12**:
how much time does it require to create the .bag file from the .pcap file